# is it possible getting facebook user's wall info only with user's id and name info?

Tags: android, facebook

In my app, I have a search bar which can search facebook user by user's name.

this search bar returns user's name and user's id value.

For example, if i search "James", search bar returns bunch of "jameses"

with thier Id like

Name: james lee 
id:102312424 
Name: james Duffy
id:123456789

I want to show these jameses' wall when my user clicks one of those 'jameses'

I belive I cant access above one of james wall with a url

http://graph.facebook.com/jamesId/home?&access_token=MyUserAccessToken

can anybody tell me alternative way to read those jameses' wall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will either need to have an access token for James that has `read_stream` permissions.  Or you need to have an access token from one of James' friends that has .

See the user fields and connections on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ and it tells you the specific permissions needed in your access token.

Comment: Yeah... looks like I cant provide james' wall to my user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. Maybe you could do it with the ones who have their walls open, but think about it: What about the ones who have their wall closed and only visible to their friends? (Which are the biggest part)